# Using property list from expl3

Tags: expl3, latex3, property-list

I'm trying to use a property list from expl3 however, I have a very simple example that fails.
Can anyone help me understand my error?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% define a propery list
\prop_new:N \my_tooltip_prop
%
\NewDocumentCommand{\CSetA}{mm}{
    \prop_gput:Nnn \my_tooltip_prop {#1} {#2}
}
%
\NewDocumentCommand{\CGetA}{m}{
    \prop_get:NnN \my_tooltip_prop {#1}
}
%
%
% Altenative
%
\cs_new_protected:Npn \CSetB #1#2 {
    \prop_gput:Nnn \my_tooltip_prop {#1} {#2}
}
%
\cs_new:Npn \CGetB #1 {
    \prop_get:NnN \my_tooltip_prop {#1}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

Hello

%\CSetA{key1}{value1}
%\CGetA{key1} % same error as with \CGetB{key2}

\CSetB{key2}{value2}
\CGetB{key2}

\end{document}
```

The error message is

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000].
\par ->valu
           e2
l.40 \end{document}
```

My system is running Kubuntu 16.10.

Comment: `\prop_get:NnN` needs *three* arguments – you only have two!

Comment: Use `\prop_item:Nn` instead of `\prop_get:NnN`.

Comment: Thank you, you are right! \prop_item:Nn is not defined anymore :( 
 
I had to change \CGetA and \CGetB to: \prop_get:NnN \my_tooltip_prop {#1} \tempVar \tempVar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way is with `\prop_item:Nn`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% define a propery list
\prop_new:N \g_leal_tooltip_prop
%
\NewDocumentCommand{\CSet}{mm}
 {
  \prop_gput:Nnn \g_leal_tooltip_prop {#1} {#2}
 }
%
\NewDocumentCommand{\CGet}{m}
 {
  \prop_item:Nn \g_leal_tooltip_prop {#1}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

Hello

\CSet{key1}{value1}
\CGet{key1}

\CSet{key2}{value2}
\CGet{key2}

\end{document}
```

The `\prop_item:Nn` function has been introduced on 2014-07-17; if you get it is undefined, your TeX distribution is lagging behind.

An almost equivalent version would be with the help of a token list variable:

```
\tl_new:N \l_leal_tooltip_temp_tl
\NewDocumentCommand{\CGet}{m}
 {
  \prop_get:NnN \g_leal_tooltip_prop {#1} \l_leal_tooltip_temp_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_leal_tooltip_temp_tl
 }
```

Comment: This »almost equivalent« version of `\prop_item:Nn` is not fully expandable.  It should be fairly easy to backport `\prop_item:Nn`.  It’s only [a few lines](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/blob/master/l3kernel/l3prop.dtx#L775).

Comment: @HenriMenke Yes, I used “almost” on purpose. I'd prefer to update the TeX distribution rather than hacking.

Comment: Thank you! My version of expl3 is from 2016/05/18 (v6512). I had previously used \prop_item:Nn but then it stopped working after an upgrade (Undefined control sequence).

Comment: @egreg :  Can you replace `\tl_new:Nn` for `\tl_new:N`?, just with the idea of keeping the answer updated, Saludos

Answer (score 1):

In ConTeXt you get property lists with a high-level interface.

```
\starttext

\setvariables
  [tooltip]
  [
    key1=value1,
    key2=value2,
  ]

\getvariable{tooltip}{key1}
\getvariable{tooltip}{key2}

\stoptext
```

Comment: Interestingly, we're currently discussing the link between property lists and keyval methods on the LaTeX team list :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve something similar to [my ConTeXt answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/344011/10995) with LuaLaTeX.  To parse the key-value list, I still use `utilities.parsers.settings_to_hash` from ConTeXt.  To do so, I have to import the necessary ConTeXt core files, namely

```
dofile(kpse.find_file("l-lpeg.lua"))
dofile(kpse.find_file("util-sto.lua"))
dofile(kpse.find_file("util-prs.lua"))
```

The following code is very generic and has an interface similar to the ConTeXt version.  It should be easy to repurpose it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\directlua{
dofile(kpse.find_file("l-lpeg.lua"))
dofile(kpse.find_file("util-sto.lua"))
dofile(kpse.find_file("util-prs.lua"))

uservariables         = uservariables or {}
uservariables.content = uservariables.content or {}

function uservariables.put(namespace,keyvals)
    local input = utilities.parsers.settings_to_hash(keyvals)

    uservariables.content[namespace] = uservariables.content[namespace] or {}

    for k,v in pairs(input) do
        uservariables.content[namespace][k] = v
    end
end

function uservariables.get(namespace,k) 
    tex.sprint(uservariables.content[namespace][k] or "")
end
}

\newcommand\setvariables[2]{%
  \directlua{uservariables.put(\unexpanded{[==[#1]==], [==[#2]==]})}}

\newcommand\getvariable[2]{%
  \directlua{uservariables.get(\unexpanded{[==[#1]==], [==[#2]==]})}}

\begin{document}

\setvariables
  {tooltip}
  {
    key1=value1,
    key2=value2,
  }

\getvariable{tooltip}{key1}
\getvariable{tooltip}{key2}

\end{document}
```